# Executing sqlplus without entry in tnsnames.ora, standalone command works and script get struck

Tags: bash, oracle, unix, sqlplus, tnsnames

I am running unix script, that executes the SQL commands to get a report, as  I do not have entry in `tnsnames.ora`, I give full description of portal in the `sqlplus` command and then the `sqlfile`. When I try to run the script the control gets struck.

I use `sqlplus -s` option to silent the prompt of username and password.
I ran the script with `ksh -x myscript.ksh` and when the script got struck, I copied the sqlplus line and ran it standalone, it works fine.

```
$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus -S 'username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS= 
(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=umyhostname)(Port=1599))) 
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=idb)))' @/usr/local/myrpt.sql
```

Comment: Try without `-S`, perhaps then you see an error message.

Comment: Do you have new-lines in your description? Try `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus -S username/password@"(DESCRIPTION=...)))"`

Comment: Is there a reason why you not simply put the description into your `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: Issue resolved after changing to "sqlplus -s" and pointing correct $ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```sh
$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus -S "username/password@umyhostname:1599/idb" @/usr/local/myrpt.sql
```

Show you script if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
oracle@esmd:/opt/oracle> more test3.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

username=SCOTT
#password lowercase
password=\"tiger\"

TNS_ALIAS='(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = zzzz.yyy.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = ESMD)
    )
)'

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo TNS_ALIAS: $TNS_ALIAS

sqlplus -s $username/$password@"$TNS_ALIAS" @test.sql



oracle@esmd:~> ksh
oracle@esmd:/opt/oracle> ./test3.ksh
username: SCOTT
password: "tiger"
TNS_ALIAS: (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = zzzz.xxx.yyy)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ESMD) ) )

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
24-06-2019 09:51:27
```